# VMware physical host doesn't boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-esxi

I am using VMware ESXi 5.1.0 to manage my VMs.

I have lost root password of the physical host.  So, I tried to reset forgotten root password of the physical host.  After doing my search I found the below link and gave it a go.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqcjBGNZtq8

The next problem arose when I rebooted the physical host after following the tutorial in the above link and it failed to boot(It only showed welcome message with "loading..." (I am going to share the screenshot below).  Then It failed with no displayed message, error or anything.

Please advise how to approach this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> [Changing a forgotten root password on an ESX/ESXi host (1317898)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1317898)
>
> ### ESXi 3.5, ESXi 4.x, ESXi 5.x and ESXi 6.x
>
> Reinstalling the ESXi host is the only supported way to reset a
>   password on ESXi.

It should be possible to (re)install a new host and attach or restore storage. Look at this as a test of your bare metal restore procedures.

Some people may have successfully removed or reset the  password in an undocumented way. But you were not, and the vendor is not going to help you. Reinstalling should be easier at that point.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't have a content.

Comment: I copied the relevant bit of content in my answer. VMware doesn't support just a root password reset.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you miss-typed while editing something.  Unless you're very familiar with vi/m, I would start by going and looking at any files I edited to make sure I didn't insert an extra character where I didn't intend to.

Comment: Hi IceMage!    I suspected that the issue emerged because of the given commands in the tutorial.  I will see if I can redo the steps and will check the modified files even though I am certain that no mistyping occured.